# --prod build with the Ionic/Capacitor app inside the Android studio

Tags: android, angular, ionic-framework, capacitor

How to do a `--prod` build with the Ionic/Capacitor app?

I have used this `ionic capacitor build android --prod`

But it shows this `To continue, build your project using Android Studio!` and open the Android studio. But it always generates Debug APK without considering `--prod` Any clue here?

**Note** Here I do not need Signed APK.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the wrong command. Use this command

`ionic build --prod && npx cap sync && npx cap open android`

This will sync the production build of your app to the native platform along with the plugins.

Comment: No difference. It still does not use the `--prod` i.e. it has a bigger bundle size.

Comment: is bundle size an issue or generating prod build? for capacitor using the `--prod` tag is all it takes for production code build.. Please add more details/focus to your question above..